# CodenameOne - Multilist is not working in the project

Tags: codenameone

Am facing some problem with populating the Multilist in Codename One.
But values are not loaded in the form. It shows blank list with checkbox.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
@Override
    protected boolean initListModelMultiList(List cmp) {
        Vector vec = new Vector();
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        h.put("User1", "List1");
        h.put("User2", "List2");
        h.put("User3", "List3");
        vec.addElement(h);
            cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(vec));
        return true;
    }
```

Below warnings are displayed in the eclipse window.
Vector vec = new Vector() is line number 279.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Vector is a raw type. References to generic type Vector should be parameterized  StateMachine.java   /Testing/src/userclasses    line 279    Java Problem
List is a raw type. References to generic type List should be parameterized  StateMachine.java   /Testing/src/userclasses    line 278    Java Problem
Hashtable is a raw type. References to generic type Hashtable should be parameterized  StateMachine.java   /Testing/src/userclasses    line 280    Java Problem
Hashtable is a raw type. References to generic type Hashtable should be parameterized  StateMachine.java   /Testing/src/userclasses    line 280    Java Problem
Vector is a raw type. References to generic type Vector should be parameterized  StateMachine.java   /Testing/src/userclasses    line 279    Java Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 3 elements in the list not in the vector and the keys for the hashtable need to match the keys defined in the multi-list see http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-list-of-items-the-easy-way.html

Sample code:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
for(int iter = 0 ; iter < 100 ; iter++) {
   Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
   h.put("Line1", "First line of row: " + iter");
   h.put("Line2", "Second line of row: " + iter");
   v.addElement(h);
}
cmp.setModel(new DefaultListModel(v));
```

Comment: I want the values loaded dynamically by listing more details dynamically.

Comment: Vector vec = new Vector();
vec.addElement("User1");
vec.addElement("User2");
vec.addElement("User3"); //This is working. 1. I need to select only few options from the list. 2. Instead of displaying MultiButton in the control, I need custom text displayed. How is that possible ?

Comment: No. You need to add 3 hashtables and the keys to the hashtable entries need to map to the settings in the MultiList e.g. Line1, Line2 etc. (line within a specific ROW).

Comment: Can you provide me a sample code ? I need to display about 20 options and user should be able to select the checkbox for some of the details listed.

Comment: Works perfectly as required. Thank You.